# put ULocale is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a hack Client in Minecraft, but it gives me an error in Eclipse.

In the code it underlines "put" in this:

```
categoryFrames.put(module.getCategory(), frame);
```

And this is the crash report

> Unexpected error
>
> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>           The method put(ULocale.Category, GuiManager.ModuleFrame) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (Category, GuiManager.ModuleFrame)

What do I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the arguments you provided are not the correct type.  When you declare your `HashMap`, you can do so the following way:

```
HashMap<String, Object> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Take a look at the declaration of your map object and take a look at the expected types.  This will take you most of the way.

If you want us to take a look at that you will have to edit your question and include the declaration of the hashmap in your question.  It would be better to include all your code.  And better than that is to check the wiki about how to ask a question here on SO and [here is the link to that resource](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).